# ElasticsearchJestHealthIndicator : Health check failed when using Jest in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using Jest at [enter link description here](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest) in my spring boot application.

Then I created the client with the example code :

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
 factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
                        .Builder("http://myhost:9200")
                        .multiThreaded(true)
 
 JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

Everything is fine. I can use this client to do all the queries I want. Happy till now.

Then the problem, when the application starts up, ElasticsearchJestHealthIndicator class is auto-initialized. But the problem is I don't know where to set the config that it will need, so it uses the default value as http://localhost:9200, which leads me to this problem:

> WARN [on(2)-127.0.0.1] s.b.a.h.ElasticsearchJestHealthIndicator : Health check failed
> io.searchbox.client.config.exception.CouldNotConnectException: Could not connect to http://localhost:9200
> at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:70)
> at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:60)

Can someone show me how to properly config it , or turn it off ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search in the reference documentation shows that Spring Boot will configure for you a `JestClient` (you can just inject it anywhere you need), and that the following configuration properties apply:

```
spring.elasticsearch.jest.uris=http://search.example.com:9200
spring.elasticsearch.jest.read-timeout=10000
spring.elasticsearch.jest.username=user
spring.elasticsearch.jest.password=secret
```

See [here for more on this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch-jest).

Comment: spring.elasticsearch.jest.uris solved the problem! Thank you     :)

Answer (score 0):

> The Jest client has been deprecated as well, since both Elasticsearch and Spring Data Elasticsearch provide official support for REST clients.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-elasticsearch